# How to create a 3-bit CRC in C++?

Tags: c++, crc, crc32

I tried to do a [CRC computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Computation_of_CRC) using C++. Since it seemed basic I thought of doing it using an array.

This is my code (Inefficient and Nonsense):

```
/*3-bit CRC Calculator in C++*/
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m[100][100]; //Array to perform calculations... store values..
    int x = 4;
    m[1][0] = 1;
    m[1][1] = 0;
    m[1][2] = 1;
    m[1][3] = 1;

    cout << "Enter the binary sequence (14 digits):\n";

    cin >> m[0][x-4];
    cin >> m[0][x-3];
    cin >> m[0][x-2];
    cin >> m[0][x-1];
    cin >> m[0][x];
    cin >> m[0][x+1];
    cin >> m[0][x+2];
    cin >> m[0][x+3];
    cin >> m[0][x+4];
    cin >> m[0][x+5];
    cin >> m[0][x+6];
    cin >> m[0][x+7];
    cin >> m[0][x+8];
    cin >> m[0][x+9];

    m[0][x+10] = 0; //3-bit crc
    m[0][x+11] = 0;
    m[0][x+12] = 0;

    while (x >= -4){
        m[2][0] = m[0][0] xor m[1][0]; //Subraction from message binary code
        m[2][1] = m[0][1] xor m[1][1];
        m[2][2] = m[0][2] xor m[1][2];
        m[2][3] = m[0][3] xor m[1][3];

        m[0][0] = m[2][1];
        m[0][1] = m[2][2];
        m[0][2] = m[2][3] ;
        x--;
    }
    cout << "CRC Value: " << m[0][0] << m[0][1] << m[0][2];
    cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Now it returns 110. :/

Comment: `while(x>=-10)`, so what would be the value of `x` after getting out of the loop? and which position of the array `m` you are trying to access after that? `-15` ?!

Comment: Ahh.. I get it... Changing while(x>=-10) to while(x>=-4) should solve the problem? and also using absolute value in the "cout<<"CRC Value: "<<m[0][x-4]<<m[0][x-3]<<m[0][x-2];" part? Updated the post with the modified code.. Thanks for the help..

Comment: At what point do you think you are accessing message bit 4 (m[0][4])?

Comment: Oh damn :/
Should've used an other variable... Thanks for pointing it out...